# Globals from one file are undefined in another

Tags: python

This is partially linked with my last question. I imported an object called current_user. I pass it in 2 variables from file 1 called guy.py, the variables are log_name and log_pass. These 2 variables are inputs from 2 entries and they're global. I made a function to import these global variables along with every other global that I have in gui.py. I'm still confused as to why the global variables are still being undefined.

This is the function which I use to import the object current_user:

```
def objects():
global log_name,log_pass
current_user = User(log_name,log_pass,score=0)
return current_user
```

And this is the function I tried using to import my global variables:

```
def global_vars():
global main_window,reg_window,name_entry,pass_entry,log_name_entry,log_pass_entry,log_name,log_pass,c,conn,query,data
```

The error I get is this:

current_user = User(log_name,log_pass,score=0)
NameError: name 'log_name' is not defined

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have to provide more information

Comment: The word "global" is misleading. Actually global variables exist in the namespace of the current module (Python code file). They must be imported (with `import`!) into another to be available.

Comment: Variables ```log_name``` and ```log_pass``` are created only when ```function compare_users``` is triggered. Try register then login first from ```tk``` window.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand you have to .py files: one is called guy.py the other I will call test.py:

so if you want to import values from guy.py to test.py. First define variables in guy.py like so:

```
log_name = yourvalue
log_pass = yourvalue
```

then go to test.py (it has to be in the same directory (to make it simple)) and import:

```
from guy import log_name, log_pass
```

now you can use these values in test.py and whenever you change the value in guy.py it will be changed in test.py. Also there is no need to make values global (for this case I think)

Comment: Doing so, gives me an error that says the tkinter entries I'm getting log_name,log_name and log pass, are undefined, but I've also made them global.

Comment: why have you defined functions inside functions?

Comment: All the functions inside main_func() are tied to tkinter buttons which are called when they're clicked.

Comment: Do you know anything about nested functions? I dont but thats what you have created and there is something about 'nonlocal' i dont know but you should

Comment: now regarding your code you should make the function return value like log_name and then you can call it on a varible like this `from gui import func` and then call it so that it returns your values `log_pass, log_name = func()[0], func()[1]`